# Hackerrank question on array manipulation using c

Tags: c

My code shows segmentation fault for test cases 7 to 13(where n=10000000 and m=100000). Why is it so? Is it because of very big values of n and m? Why is it not showing time limit exceeded if numbers are very big? Here is the link to the question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem?isFullScreen=false

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
long long n,m;
scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&m);
long long queries[m+1][4];
for( long long i=1;i<=m;i++)
{
    scanf("%lld",&queries[i][1]);
    scanf("%lld",&queries[i][2]);
    scanf("%lld",&queries[i][3]);
}

long long a[n+1];
for(long long i=1;i<=n;i++)
    a[i]=0;
for(long long i=1;i<=m;i++)
{
    for(long long j=queries[i][1];j<=queries[i][2];j++)
        a[j]=a[j]+queries[i][3];
}

long long max;
max=0;
for(long long i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(max<a[i])
        max=a[i];
}
printf("%lld",max);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m=100000` `long long queries[m+1][4];` `n=10000000` `long long a[n+1];`  That's a lot of memory. Like 80 megabytes of memory.

Comment: You can't have 80 MB in automatic variables. You could try using dynamic allocation.

Comment: You have a stack overflow. The run-time system or OS aborts your program.

Comment: Although the Hackerrank problem describes an array, you do not need to use that full array to record the necessary data. You are supposed to think of another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Got it.Thank you very much.